# std::ostream to QString?

Tags: c++, qt, exception

Is there a way to convert an std::ostream to a QString?

Allow me to expand in case it is useful:
I am writing a program in C++/Qt and I used to (not) deal with / debug exceptions by just using std::cout, as in for example:

```
std::cout << "Error in void Cat::eat(const Bird &bird): bird has negative weight" << std::endl;
```

Now I want to throw errors as QStrings and catch them later, so I would now write instead:

```
throw(QString("Error in void Cat::eat(const Bird &bird): bird has negative weight"));
```

My issue is that I've been overloading the operator << so that I can use it with many objects, for instance a `Bird`, so I would actually have written:

```
std::cout << "Error in void Cat::eat(const Bird &bird): bird " << bird << " has negative weight" << std::endl;
```

Is there a way that I can throw this as a QString now? I would like to be able to write something like:

```
std::ostream out;
out << "Error in void Cat::eat(const Bird &bird): bird " << bird << " has negative weight" << std::endl;
throw(QString(out));
```

but that doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Try creating a `std::stringstream` from your string parts, then using `ss.str()` in the constructor for the `QString`? I.e. `throw(QString(ss.str()));`

Comment: Should be `QString::fromStdString(ss.str())` - sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) as follows:

```
std::stringstream out;
//   ^^^^^^
out << "Error in void Cat::eat(const Bird &bird): bird " << bird << " has negative weight" << std::endl;
throw(QString::fromStdString(out.str()));
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Specifically, the `std::stringstream::str` member function will get you an `std::string`, which you can then pass to the [`QString::fromStdString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromStdString) static member function to create a `QString`.

Answer (score 2):

The `std::stringstream` class can receive input from overloaded `<<` operators. Using this, combined with its ability to pass its value as a `std::string`, you can write

```
#include <sstream>
#include <QtCore/QString>

int main() {
    int value=2;
    std::stringstream myError;
    myError << "Here is the beginning error text, and a Bird: " << value;
    throw(QString::fromStdString(myError.str()));
}
```